# Visual C++ Debugging problem

Tags: debugging, visual-c++

I have been having constant struggle with Visual Studio debugger and finally got fed up and seeking help. There are some issues constantly causing trouble. If you have any solutions I will be grateful

1. Trying to watch a function that has const and non-const versions results in ambiguous symbol error (CXX0039)
2. Trying to get value of a function in a template class randomly gives member function is not defined error (CXX0052)
3. Casting a template type variable results in bad type cast, even to its own type (CXX0019)

I have visual studio 2010 Professional with SP1

**EDIT**
In #2, I am sure that inlining is off.

Thanks in advance,
Cem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that the best option is to modify autoexp.dat and show transformed variables. At start its a bit hard but when you are done its even better than getting these problems fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I've just experienced the same problem...

Found the answer after some searching on MSDN.

[Visual Studio 2005 C++ CXX0052: member function not present](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/vsdebug/thread/b38b56ef-4766-475e-9e21-505a87fb3fee)!

Basically what you need to do is to store the result in a temp variable, and view this temp variable in the Watch or Locals window.
Far from an ideal solution I guess, but it works ( on VS2010 SP1 ).